# CakePHP save() doesn't save data

Tags: cakephp, insert, save

I don't see anything wrong with my code. But it does not save data:

```
<?php
    class ProductsController extends AppController{
        var $name = 'Products';
        //var $helpers = array('Form');
        //var $scaffold;

        function index(){
            $this->Product->recursive = 1;
            $products = $this->Product->find('all');
            $this->set('products',$products);
            //pr($products);
        }

        function add(){
            $categories = $this->Product->Category->find('list',array(
                'field'=>array('Category.categoryName')
            ));
            $this->set('categories',$categories);

            if(!empty($this->data)){
                if($this->Product->save($this->data)){
                    $this->Session->setFlash('Saved');
                }
            }


        }
    }
?>
```

it flashes "Saved" but nothing is being inserted in my table. What could possibly be wrong when it should be functioning properly. :(

Below is my add.ctp model:

```
<h2>ADD</h2>

<?php echo $this->Form->create('Product',array('action'=>'add')); ?>
<?php
    echo $form->input('ProductName');
    echo $form->input('categories');
    echo $form->end('DONE');
?>
```

Comment: Well i saw my mistake with the help of my bestfriend ever "pr()" function. My add.ctp is wrong. It should go like this:

    <h2>ADD</h2>
    
    <?php echo $this->Form->create('Product',array('action'=>'add')); ?>
    <?php
     echo $form->input('productName');
     echo $form->input('category_id');
     echo $form->end('DONE');
    ?>

Comment: try checking pr($this->data) before save... do you get the posted data..?

Comment: yep.. i did.. :)  thank you so much to pr() function.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the create() method before to save

```
function add(){
        $categories = $this->Product->Category->find('list',array(
            'field'=>array('Category.categoryName')
        ));
        $this->set('categories',$categories);

        if(!empty($this->data)){

            $this->Product->create();
            if($this->Product->save($this->data)){
                $this->Session->setFlash('Saved');
            }
        }


    }
```